# I want to access file system and show video or images in my component in react native

Tags: react-native, local-storage, file-manager

```js
 const getdata = async () => {
    const downloadDirPath = `${RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath}/Download`;
    console.log(downloadDirPath)
    RNFS.readDir(downloadDirPath)
     .then((result) => {
       // Filter for image files
       console.log('ddddd',result.isFile());
       setImages(result); // Update state with image URIs
    })
  }
```

"This is my code and I am getting a folder with this code but not files. I want to access files like images, videos, pdf."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.